# How to delay for agent response for Dialogflow cx

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am using dialogflow with audiocode integration. How to I delay agent to wait for response so that the end user could complete his response?

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try [Dasha](https://dasha.ai). If I understood you correctly, using DashaScript you can add a delay like that:

```
#waitForSpeech(1000);
```

https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/dasha-script-language/built-in-functions/#waitforspeech-blocking-call